# Convert HTML table to XML using PHP (DOMDocument?)

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I'm looking to convert the below HTML Table markup into an XML format.

```
<table class='tbl-class'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Island</th>
      <th>Number of nights</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Guadeloupe</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Antigua</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
</table>
```

I would ideally like the XML output to be something like this:

```
<location>
  <island>Guadeloupe</island>
  <nights>1</nights>
</location>
<location>
  <island>Antigua</island>
  <nights>5</nights>
</location>
```

I'm currently attempting to use DOMDocument to do this but have little experience with it to get anywhere. So far i've done the following: - I think there's much more i need to be doing in the foreach loop but unsure what..

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($convertedString);
$classname = 'tbl-class';
$finder = new DomXPath($doc);
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}

$convertedString = $doc->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 1):

I find that using SimpleXML is as it's name implies - simpler.  This code reads the XML and as you have - finds the `<table>` element.

Then using `foreach()` it uses SimpleXML's ability to refer to the element hierarchy as objects, so `$table[0]->tbody->tr` refers to the `<tr>` elements in the `<tbody>` section of the table.

It then combines each of the `<td>` elements with the corresponding label from `$headers`...

```
$xml= simplexml_load_string($convertedString);

$classname = 'tbl-class';
$table = $xml->xpath("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");

$headers = ["island", "nights"];
$out = new SimpleXMLElement("<locations />");
foreach ( $table[0]->tbody->tr as $tr ){
    $location = $out->addChild("location");
    $key = 0;
    foreach ( $tr->td as $td )  {
        $location->addChild($headers[$key++], (string)$td);
    }
}

echo $out->asXML();
```